# Is it a bug in Ruby or it is the right behaviour in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am not able to figure out why in the 3rd Ruby statement is throwing a syntax error when there is no space after comma but space after puts.

```
vivek@P11-AS MINGW64 ~
$ irb
Switch to inspect mode.
puts("Hello, World!","Good bye, World!")
puts("Hello, World!","Good bye, World!")
Hello, World!
Good bye, World!
nil


puts ("Hello, World!")
puts ("Hello, World!")
Hello, World!
nil


puts ("Hello, World!","Good bye, World!")
puts ("Hello, World!","Good bye, World!")
SyntaxError: (irb):7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
puts ("Hello, World!","Good bye, World!")
                      ^
(irb):7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
        from C:/Ruby21-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

puts("Hello, World!", "Good bye, World!")
puts("Hello, World!", "Good bye, World!")
Hello, World!
Good bye, World!
nil

exit()
exit()

vivek@P11-AS MINGW64 ~
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right behaviour in Ruby. Function call can follow one of these two patterns:

```
function(arg1, arg2...)
function arg1, arg2...
```

but not

```
function (arg1, arg2...)
```

i.e. when you use parentheses for the arguments, there cannot be a space between the function name and the parenthesis.

Note that this:

```
function (arg1)
```

is actually just equivalent to

```
function((arg1))
```

and thus valid. However,

```
function (arg1, arg2)
```

is trying to be parsed as

```
function((arg1, arg2))
```

which does not fit Ruby grammar.

The comma does not have any spacing rules that I can remember; all of these are valid:

```
function(arg1, arg2)
function(arg1 , arg2)
function(arg1 ,arg2)
function(arg1,arg2)
```

but the coding styles prefer the first one.